# 讷 as nò, an exclamation meaning "Here you go"

Tags: word, expressions

Encountered this in the Pimsleur transcript:

> Nánrén: Wô gêi nî yìdiânr Rénmínbì. **Nò**.
>   Shí jiû kuài Rénmínbì. Xiànzài nî yôu
>   duöshâo qián?
>
> 男人：我给你一点儿人民币。**讷**。 十九
>   块人民币。现在你有多少钱？
>
> Man: I’ll give you some Renminbi. **Here you
>   go.** 14 Renminbi. Now you have how much
>   money?

They use it many times and always in the context of someone giving money or an item in a business transaction.  The translation is always "here you go" or "here you are".

I can't find any other uses of this word in this way, or any dictionary mentioning this meaning.  Is this a common expression?  Is it regional?

Is this the same thing as 喏 / nuò?

Comment: There is no syllable „no“ in standard Mandarin. Readings I am aware of are 1)na4 in 樸訥， 2)ne4 in 剛毅木訥。

Comment: My impression of 讷 is, it is similar to '嗱' /naa4/ in Cantonese: 我俾啲人民币你吖。嗱。 十九 蚊人民币。而家你有几多钱？ (嗱 - here you go)

Comment: I would say it should be 喏 instead of 呐，it should be a typo.

Comment: @zyy It's not a simple typo, since it occurs multiple times, including in their vocabulary lists and glossary. It could be that one person was responsible for the whole document and confused the two.  I don't see how they'd accidentally use a non-standard pinyin syllable, though.

Comment: @BenJackson It seems like to be the case, you could look at the [explanation](http://xh.5156edu.com/html3/3453.html) of 讷 and you will find it only means 语言迟钝。

Comment: as @Shadoweats answered, you need to combine it with a physical gesture of handing something out for the translation *here you go* to work. This is the same as in English, where saying "here" doesn't automatically mean anything, but the physical gesture makes the intention clear.'

Comment: @BenJackson Is it read "Nò" in the recordings?

Comment: @user3306356 Yes, like a pinyin "no", so close to "nuo", not  like English "no"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the correct character might be

**吶 na4 used as an auxiliary word 语助词**

We say 吶 na4 sometimes when giving someone something, so saying 吶 + the gesture of giving the thing away does translate to "here you go". The way I have heard it the most is "呐，这个给你".

However, I'd only use 吶 in informal speech with family or friends. It's quite casual and I don't think it's appropriate for professional settings, including business transactions.

> Reference Notes

1. In the [Zdic entry](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E5%91%90) of 吶, it lists 讷 as interchangeable with 吶 when pronounced ne4 which means slow of speech or to speak with a stammer (讲话迟钝或口吃). I'm guessing this might be where typo stems from.
2. From the same [Zdic entry](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E5%91%90) mentioned above, one of the meanings of 吶 is 表示提醒注意 to get someone's attention. I think this "getting attention" + "the gesture of handing over something" combined implies the meaning of "here you go".
3. As an auxiliary word 語助詞, you can use 吶 in other cases without the meaning "here you go", for example "天吶" equivalent to "天啊" which is an exclamation similar to "Gee" or "Yikes" or "Oh".
4. 吶 is commonly seen as part of the word 吶喊 which means to shout / cry out.

Answer (score 1):

**喏** (or 诺) seems to fit the description here.

If we look at *KEY*’s definition:

> nuò
>
> INTERJ
> 1 {regional} here!; there!; look! (used when showing or offering sth to sb
> 2 {classical} (the old form of nuò 諾/诺) promise, affirm, agree
> 3 (say) yes

First off nuò would carry effectively the same pronunciation as the given: nò.

Secondly the idea of say 喏 when handing something to someone is explicitly mentioned here in definition number one.

Comment: It mentions that it is *regional* but I’m not sure what region it’s from - I’ve never heard it in the Southwest though.